# Migrate/Clone bootable OS partition to a bigger partition

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd, migration

I have a single-partition 512 GB SSD with Windows 10 installed, and want to migrate it to a bigger 1 TB SSD. I tried EaseUS and Minitool Partition Wizard, but they are not able to resize the partition. So instead of having one 1 TB partition I end up with two 512 GB ones -- one that is cloned, and the "leftover" one. Is there a way to migrate and resize the partition?

Comment: I am going to be careful here.  There is a tool that I have used in the past that allows you to migrate your OS to a new SDD.  It works, it’s not free, but the company has spammed this community.  All you would do is migrate your OS, it transfers the required MBR/EFI partition, then within the OS extend the partition on the larger drive.  If you google “migrate os” you will find the program.  I will not submit an answer nor will I name the company, their tactics are despicable but the program works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're almost there.

After you clone the drive using the tool of your choice, boot Windows, then run `diskmgmt.msc` to start Disk Management. Right-click on the volume to be expanded, and click **Extend**. Follow the prompts and your 512 GB volume will be extended to consume the remaining unused space.

Note that the unused space must *immediately* follow the partition you are extending. This *will* be the case in your situation, but it's worth being aware of this requirement for future use of the Extend capability.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought extension is possible only for ext* type partitions

Comment: You're correct...In older versions of Windows this wasn't possible with the boot volume.

Comment: Just curious -- did this feature appear only on Windows 10 or on some previous version?

Comment: @Cons it was added in either Vista or Windows 7. I didn't work with Vista enough to remember which...